# How can I highlight given values in a generated numeric sequence?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I often receive unordered lists of document IDs.  I can sort and print them easy enough, but I'd like to print a line for each available document and show an asterisk (or anything really, just to highlight) next to all values in the given list.

Such as ...

```
$ ./t.sh "1,4,3" 5

1*
2
3*
4*
5

$
```

The first parameter is the unordered list, and the second is the total number of documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "available document" you mean an "existing file on disk", then assuming you have 5 total files, and you are checking to see if you have 1, 4 and 3.  The following script will produce sorted output.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Store the original IFS
ORGIFS=$IFS
#Now Set the Internal File Separater to a comma
IFS=","

###Identify which elements of the array we do have and store the results
### in a separate array
#Begin a loop to process each array element
for X in ${1} ; do
        if [[ -f ${X} ]] ; then
                vHAVE[$X]=YES
        fi
done


#Now restore IFS
IFS=$ORGIFS

#Process the sequence of documents, starting at 1 and ending at $2.
for Y in $(seq 1 1 $2) ; do
        #Check if the sequence exists in our inventoried array and mark accordingly.
       if [[ ${vHAVE[$Y]} == YES ]] ; then
                echo "$Y*"
        else
                echo "$Y"
        fi
done
```

Returns the result:

```
rtcg@testserver:/temp/test# ls
rtcg@testserver:/temp/test# touch 1 3 4
rtcg@testserver:/temp/test# /usr/local/bin/t "1,4,3" 5
1*
2
3*
4*
5
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me on your example.

1. Generate a sequence of the length given by the user
2. Split the first argument of your script (it will gives you an array `A` for example)
3. Use the function `contains` to check if one element from `A` is in the sequence generated by the step one

I don't check the arguments length and you should do that to have a more proper script.

```
#!/bin/bash

function contains() {
    local n=$#
    local value=${!n}
    for ((i=1;i < $#;i++)) {
        if [ "${!i}" == "${value}" ]; then
            echo "y"
            return 0
        fi
    }
    echo "n"
    return 1
}

IFS=', ' read -a array <<< $1

for i in $(seq $2); do
    if [ $(contains "${array[@]}" "${i}") == "y" ]; then
        echo "${i}*"
    else
        echo "${i}"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use parameter substitution to build an extended pattern that can be used to match document numbers to the list of documents to mark.

```
#!/bin/bash

# 1,4,3 -> 1|4|3
to_mark=${1//,/|}
for(( doc=1; doc <= $2; doc++)); do
    # @(1|4|3) matches 1, 4 or 3
    printf "%s%s\n" "$doc" "$( [[ $doc = @($to_mark) ]] && printf "*" )"
done
```